# Aid in understanding WordPress dropdown code

Tags: php, wordpress

Ive been asked to create a new dropdown menu in wordpress. I have never used word press and i have also never coded in php before. I've managed to find a piece of code for an existing dropdown menu but i do not understand how it works. i was hoping someone could help explain it to me so i can get an understanding of what is going on.

```
<?php if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical($taxonomy) ) : ?>
    <tr class="form-field term-parent-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><label for="parent"><?php _ex( 'Parent', 'term parent' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <?php
            $dropdown_args = array(
                'hide_empty'       => 0,
                'hide_if_empty'    => false,
                'taxonomy'         => $taxonomy,
                'name'             => 'parent',
                'orderby'          => 'name',
                'selected'         => $tag->parent,
                'exclude_tree'     => $tag->term_id,
                'hierarchical'     => true,
                'show_option_none' => __( 'None' ),
            );

            /** This filter is documented in wp-admin/edit-tags.php */
            $dropdown_args = apply_filters( 'taxonomy_parent_dropdown_args', $dropdown_args, $taxonomy, 'edit' );
            wp_dropdown_categories( $dropdown_args ); ?>
            <?php if ( 'category' == $taxonomy ) : ?>
            <p class="description"><?php _e('Categories, unlike tags, can have a hierarchy. You might have a Jazz category, and under that have children categories for Bebop and Big Band. Totally optional.'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: What's your specific question? Ideally, you should be asing about a specific problem you're having, and how to fix it. Whereas this is quite a general 'help me out', which aren't really allowed on here. But I'm sure we'll help if you explain a bit more.

Comment: Sorry, well i want to create a drop down menu that simple has yes or no as the two options. The code i showed is all I've managed to find that already exists and I'm not too sure how it works, such as i don't understand what a taxonomy is

Comment: Then you're better off just using standard HTML. The `wp_dropdown_categories` functions as you're using here, does just that. Shows the Wordpress categories in a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, tell us what kind of dropdown you're looking for. WHat do you want to have inside the dropdown menu? As your code is currently set to show category links to your posts.

This might be more useful, if you read the Wordpress codex about this function, and look through your code to try and follow it.

You can also try changing the arguments to change the output of the dropdown.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

Comment: Thanks, ill have a look at it and see if it helps

Comment: After your latest comment, I actually don't think you should be using any Wordpress function to create a dropdown at all, because if you just want a 'Yes' or 'No', none of the WP functions will do that.

Comment: What essentially is the dropdown going to be used for, in what context? That might make it a bit clearer to understand what needs to be used. Why does it need PHP for example?

Comment: Well im working on an existing word press site, the dropdown box that i have been asked to make is asking for when an admin wants to create a new product for the website, they have the option to include the new product on the home page. The reason for php is that all the pages for word press are currently in php

Comment: How are new products created? This sounds quite in-depth actually, and might need some serious developing, which if you've never used PHP before.. could really take a while.

Comment: I've managed to make the drop menu now using html within the php file, I'm now just trying to save the value that has been selected.

Comment: Which file are you editing? If it's a core Wordpress file, you shouldn't be doing that at all. I don't know enough about your set up, but if you're using a plugin for your products, then that will help us a bit. Just trying to understand how your site works.

Comment: Yeah the more i look into this the more difficult it is seeming, especially with my limited knowledge, the product is created on the word press side of the site and honestly that's about as much as i can figure out to be honest, sorry it isn't much to go ff.

Comment: I think it is a core wordpress file.

Comment: Is the site live? Are you able to create a temporary admin login so I can see what it's like?

Comment: I don't think i have the permissions to do that, I'm only a placement student.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get anywhere really, there's just not enough information to go on unfortunately. Maybe by making some serious edits to your question to include a much more specific area of where you're coding (like where exactly you want the dropdown box), and what file you think it should be in. Screenshots are all helpful, just so you know. That might be a better option to get started.

Comment: Alright, well i just talked to my boss and he said to just leave it aside for now and work on something else. But when i come back to it I'll definitely do that. Thanks for all your help anyway